# Jasper Report makes Vaadin app to crash

Tags: jasper-reports, vaadin

I have a web app developed using Vaadin Framework and I use Jasper reports to generates some reports. The code is as follows:

```
// Vaadin Button Listener
   JasperDesign desenho = JRXmlLoader.load( layout );
    JasperReport r= JasperCompileManager.compileReport( desenho );

    // create some params and resultSet

    JRResultSetDataSource jrRS = new JRResultSetDataSource( resultSet );

    //Do some stuff

    JasperPrint impressao = JasperFillManager.fillReport( r, params, jrRS );
    JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer( impressao , true );
    viewer.show();
```

after user press 'Show Report' button the reports is presented in a jasper viewer  window

[image]

The user can still use the web app MEANWHILE this Jasper viewer window is open but after user close it the web app generate an communication error. Showing
JSON text error and sometimes also a Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the report generation taking a long time?

Comment: No, the report is generate good, the problem seems (I'm pretty sure) to be that when this Jasper Viewer Window is close it shutdown the tomcat server. The reason dunno!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete explanation can be found on [this link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/why-jasperviewer-closing-my-tomcat-server):

The short answer is to change `true` to `false` on the below line:

```
JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer( impressao , true );
```

That is the isExitOnClose parameter, it desactivates call t System.exit(0) on the Jasper viewer that causes Tomcat to close.